# Как при нажатии на textEdit очистить его?

Tags: pyqt5, pyside2

Как при нажатии на textEdit очистить его?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: @S. Nick мне бы хотелось при нажатии на textEdit удалять его содержимое, например: у нас там было написано Input your name... тогда после нажатия мышкой там будет пусто

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#placeholderText-prop